# How to implement mutable PickleTypes that automatically update on change

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy offers the [`PickleType`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType) and offers [mutation tracking](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html) for any type that is mutable (like a dict).

The SQLAlchemy documentation mentions that this is the way to implement a mutable `PickleType` but it does not state exactly how to proceed with it.

*Note*: I want to store a dict in the `PickleType`.

How do you implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the documentation mentions some examples, it is not sufficient in my eyes, so I will add my implementation here that can be used to implement a mutable dict that is pickled and stored in the database.

Use the [`MutableDict`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/mutable.html#establishing-mutability-on-scalar-column-values) example from the docs:

```
class MutableDict(Mutable, dict):

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, MutableDict):
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                return MutableDict(value)
            return Mutable.coerce(key, value)
        else:
            return value

    def __delitem(self, key):
        dict.__delitem__(self, key)
        self.changed()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.changed()

    def __getstate__(self):
        return dict(self)

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.update(self)
```

Now create a column to be tracked:

```
class MyModel(Base):
    data = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(PickleType))
```

I would like to see some other examples that are maybe more advanced or possibly use different data structures. What would a generic approach for `pickle` look like? Is there one (I suppose not, or SQLAlchemy would have one).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with.  It wraps any type and detects any attribute sets and calls Mutable.changed().  It also wraps function calls and detects changes by taking a snapshot of the object before and after and comparing.  Should work for Pickleable types...

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import Mutable

class MutableTypeWrapper(Mutable):
    top_attributes = ['_underlying_object',
                      '_underlying_type',
                      '_last_state', 
                      '_snapshot_update', 
                      '_snapshot_changed', 
                      '_notify_if_changed',
                      'changed',
                      '__getstate__',
                      '__setstate__',
                      'coerce']

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, MutableTypeWrapper):
            try:
                return MutableTypeWrapper(value)
            except:
                return Mutable.coerce(key, value)
        else:
            return value

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self._underlying_object

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self._underlying_type = type(state)
        self._underlying_object = state

    def __init__(self, underlying_object, underlying_type=None):
        if (underlying_object is None and underlying_type is None):  
            print('Both underlying object and type are none.')
            raise RuntimeError('Unable to create MutableTypeWrapper with no underlying object or type.')

        if (underlying_object is not None):
            self._underlying_object = underlying_object
        else:
            self._underlying_object = underlying_type()

        if (underlying_type is not None):
            self._underlying_type = underlying_type
        else:
            self._underlying_type = type(underlying_object)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if (attr in MutableTypeWrapper.top_attributes):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)

        orig_attr = self._underlying_object.__getattribute__(attr)
        if callable(orig_attr):
            def hooked(*args, **kwargs):
                self._snapshot_update()
                result = orig_attr(*args, **kwargs)
                self._notify_if_changed()
                # prevent underlying from becoming unwrapped
                if result == self._underlying_object:
                    return self
                return result
            return hooked
        else:
            return orig_attr

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if (attr in MutableTypeWrapper.top_attributes):
            object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
            return

        self._underlying_object.__setattr__(attr, value)

        self.changed()

    def _snapshot_update(self):
        self._last_state = pickle.dumps(self._underlying_object,
                                        pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    def _snapshot_changed(self):
        return self._last_state != pickle.dumps(self._underlying_object,
                                                pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    def _notify_if_changed(self):
        if (self._snapshot_changed()):
            self.changed()
```

And then use it with PickleType as follows:

```
class TestModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'testtable'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    obj = Column(MutableTypeWrapper.as_mutable(PickleType))
```

The disadvantage here is the underlying class is snapshotted before every function call, and then changes are compared after in order to verify if the underlying object has changed.  This will have a significant performance impact.

The other way to ensure that your PickleType objects are updated when you modify them is to copy and assign them before committing changes.