# SQLAlchemy committing pickle types

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, commit, pickle

I'm having an issue committing changes to pickle types (lists) in sqlalchemy. It will act as if nothing happened after the committal.

Here's my my function where I try to commit:

```
def commit_move(game_id, player, move):
    game = game_query(game_id)
    if player == 'human':
        game.human_spaces.append(move)
    if player == 'ai':
        game.ai_spaces.append(move)
    game.available_spaces.remove(move)
    print game.human_spaces
    print game.ai_spaces
    print game.available_spaces
    print "----"
    session.add(game)
    session.commit()
```

here's how the table is setup:

```
class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'game'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    human_spaces = Column(PickleType)
    ai_spaces = Column(PickleType)
    available_spaces = Column(PickleType)
```

here's the code I'm using to test it:

```
game_id = create_game()
print game_id
print get_available_spaces(game_id)
print get_human_spaces(game_id)
print get_ai_spaces(game_id)
print "---------"
commit_move(game_id, 'human', 7)
print get_available_spaces(game_id)
print get_human_spaces(game_id)
print get_ai_spaces(game_id)
```

and here's what the good ol' terminal is telling me:

```
1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[]
[]
---------
[7]
[]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
----
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[]
[]
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing here, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a little more detail to the question you are asking? Perhaps what you desire the output to be?

Comment: My question is this: what can I do so that the changes I make to these lists properly commit to the database? 

The bottom block of code shows what is printed in the terminal. The middle portion of that block shows the values that I desire, and they are correct right before the committal. But after I commit, (bottom portion) it shows that the values are not changed in the database.

Is there something I'm missing? I have a feeling it has to do with the PickleType, but I am not entirely sure and was hoping I could get some feedback with somebody who has more experience with sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the ORM is not alerted to changes inside a mutable type, like a list. SQLAlchemy therefore offers mutation tracking with the `sqlalchemy.ext.mutable` extension.

From the examples in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html), in particular with reference to the `sqlalchemy.ext.mutable.MutableList` class, it looks like the column declaration should go (e.g.):

```
human_spaces = Column(MutableList.as_mutable(PickleType))
```

I quote from the documentation on the `as_mutable` method:
"This establishes listeners that will detect ORM mappings against the given type, adding mutation event trackers to those mappings."

Comment: You might also try the approach described in the last line of this [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27981144/5869747): "The other way to ensure that your PickleType objects are updated when you modify them is to copy and assign them before committing changes."

Answer (score 1):

I've written a package to help make this easy.  You can choose different encodings, including `pickle`, and easily dump and store objects to a database.  It can connect to any database that `sqlalchemy` understands.  There is a dictionary interface to a SQL table, and you can store any type that `dill` can serialize:

```
>>> import klepto
>>> db = klepto.archives.sqltable_archive('playgame')
>>> db['human'] = [1,2,3,4]
>>> db['ai'] = [1,2]
>>> db
sqltable_archive('sqlite:///:memory:?table=playgame', {'ai': [1, 2], 'human': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, cached=True)
>>> db.dump()
>>>
```