# flask-sqlalchemy append to pickletype doesn't update

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following flask-sqlalchemy table:

```
class Repo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    followers = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable=False)
    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
```

Let's say I make the following row and push it to the database:

```
repo = Repo(
    name='My Repo',
    followers=[
        {'name': 'Johnny', 'id': 34752, 'views': 6},
        {'name': 'Mike', 'id': 69241, 'views': 3}
    ]
)
db.session.add(repo)
db.session.commit()
```

If I want to change that row, I should be able to do the following; however, the database doesn't reflect the change.

```
repo.data.append({'name': 'Jessica', 'id': 12941, 'views': 12})
print(len(repo.data))
# 3
db.session.commit()
print(len(repo.data))
# 2
```

I've figured out the following workaround but I'd like to know why the original method doesn't work as expected.

```
data = list(repo.data)
data.append({'name': 'Jessica', 'id': 12941, 'views': 12})
repo.data = data
db.session.commit()
print(len(repo.data))
# 3
```

Comment: Because SQLAlchemy keeps track of references. As long as the references are the same, it does not see any change hence it does not commit the difference.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so I need to perform the workaround for all list manipulation operations, e.g. `append`, `remove`, `pop`, etc. because they will all retain the same reference?

Comment: correct. I faced the same problem when I implemented a JSON field: changes to the JSON field are not written back. A workaround is to assign a new dictionary instead.

Comment: That, or use mutation tracking: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html

Comment: This answer is pretty much what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37317081/2681632

Comment: Willem great answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLAlchemy committing pickle types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310770/sqlalchemy-committing-pickle-types)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sqlalchemy keep track of changes of PickleType column, you need to set it to `mutable=true`. in your example:

```
followers = db.Column(db.PickleType(mutable=True), nullable=False)
```